# How to create a custom search folder that searches "follow up" and "under #### folder"?

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2010

I know how to create a custom search folder in Outlook 2010 to show all "follow up" mails, but I'd like to find those emails that only contained in the specified "####" folder.

How can I do that?

Example:

```
Inbox
├── SubFolder1
└── SubFolder2
```

Search: All mails with "follow up" and in "SubFolder1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it myself. The outlook search folder UI has just too many options and it's very easy to overlook those important ones.

1. Right click search folder to create new search folder
2. Scroll all the way down and select "Create a custom Search Folder"
3. Give it a name
4. Hit "Browse..." to manually specify which folder you want to search.

   - Don't check the root folder. (it will search everything, which is not what you want)
   - To include subfolders, there is a check box "Search subfolders" at the bottom of the form. (but its checked state isn't synced with the checkboxs in the folder selection tree)
5. Hit ok to close the form and hit "Criteria..". Go to "More Choices" and check "Only items which: are flagged by me".
6. Done.